# how to debug spark GUI if its not working

Tags: apache-spark

My SPARK GUI is not working though I can see my 4040 port is listening whenever I start any spark-submit job.

netstat -an | grep 4040
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:4040          :::*                    LISTEN

when I give address of my spark master server in my browser , it gives "This site can’t be reached".

I am not sure why it is not responding despite of listening on designated port. I also tried to see in /var/log/spark/ but non of log files gets updated after hitting web URL.

any pointer/suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found an answer. I changed configuration in /etc/hosts
from

## 127.0.0.1      localhost

to
my machine ip   localhost

Now I can see my Spark GUI. Though it is still not giving relevant data but thats another problem to solve now.